# PIL smudges image when I overlay another image on it

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using the following code to overlay an image onto another image using PIL

```
path = "/home/blah.png"
background = Image.open(path)
product = Image.open("/home/51tmBaivYhL._SL75_.jpg")
background.paste(product, (20,40))
background.save("/home/newImage.jpg")
```

These are the images I'm using as the background https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuJu1.png , product https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg0Vh.jpg and this is what the result is showing up as https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Rzu.jpg

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks.

EDIT: Also, when I try `background.paste(product, (20,40), product)`, I get the error "ValueError: bad transparency mask"

Comment: You gave the same links for the product and result, I think the result is missing. It's hard to know what your complaint is without it.

Comment: Also the "product" image is so small as to be useless.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've made the changes. @agf, any image really is causing the problem of the background getting 'smudged' at the top right, and a gray background coming on for some reason.

Comment: If you get an error on the `paste` step, how did you get the result image at all? Please post exactly what you did to get that image.

Comment: @agf, ugh sorry, I'm making typos all over. If I added an additional parameter to the paste method, that is when I get the error. I've made changes to my edit. I'm using this code for a startup and for that reason am not pasting the exact code, but this is essentially what I did. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with PIL.  The problem is the background is a .png, and you are composing it, and then outputting it as a .jpg.

.png is lossless, very good for synthetic images like your background.  .jpg is lossy, very good for natural images like photographs.  When you output your background as .jpg, it will contain compression artifacts, what you call "smudges".

Output your final image as a .png.  It will be more bytes than a .jpg, but will look better.

Answer (score 2):

You're opening a background PNG image with transparency and saving the result as a .JPG without transparency. The colors in the transparent area are probably leftovers from the image editor you used to create the PNG.